# how to select the entire tableview when the user clicks the first index path of the uitableview?

Tags: objective-c

As i am new to objective c.In my project if i select the first row of the uitableview the remaining table rows have to select .I also tried the below code but it will select only the first row as default.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [_mytableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

Comment: Iterate over `i < datasource.count` and set `cellForRowAtIndexPath: i` selected.

Comment: can u please give the sample source code how to done this